How to slot attributes into an element?
I am making a custom select component where the markup of the options should be able to be different when the option is shown in the display vs when it is shown in the dropdown.
Acheiving this is simple using the template and slot element, however, I do not know how to get the data attributes from the option to put inside the img element in the template.
I need a declarative way to do this because I will be using Static Site Generation (SSG) in my project which means I can't implement this feature by overriding the "select(option)" method. The reason why this wont work is because if an option is already pre-select, my server would not know how to build the display yet, and I do not wish to use loading states here as avoiding that is the entire point of SSG to begin with.
Do I need to build my own slot component which can slot attributes or are there some native way to do this? Or is there a completely different approach which can make this work?
The only other thing I can think of is also declaring a script element with the select logic but I am concerned about the security implications of running that on the server.
<my-select>
    <my-select-display>
        <template>
            <img> <!-- Need a way to declaratively slot src and alt attributes here -->
            <slot name="text"></slot>
        </template>
    </my-select-display>
    <my-select-options>
        <my-select-option data-src="/images/flags/flag-1.png" data-alt="Flag 1">
            <span slot="text">Option 1</span>
        </my-select-option>
        <my-select-option data-src="/images/flags/flag-2.png" data-alt="Flag 2">
            <span slot="text">Option 2</span>
        </my-select-option>
        <my-select-option data-src="/images/flags/flag-3.png" data-alt="Flag 3">
            <span slot="text">Option 3</span>
        </my-select-option>
    </my-select-options>
</my-select>


Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet with the [< >] button in the editor. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.
